# Indicating a 'castable' generic type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I have a generic class where the generic values in the class are always 'numeric' (they're guaranteed to always be `Int`s, `Float`s or `Double`s.) These values need to be used in some calculations where floating-point precision is important:

```
protocol Numeric {
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

func pointAtPercentageOfRange<T where T: Numeric>(min: T, max: T, percentage: Double) -> Double {
    let range = max - min
    return min + (percentage * CGFloat(range))
}
```

But, the compiler doesn't like this... Is there a way to express that a generic type is 'down-castable' to another type?

Comment: Implicit (C-style) promotions are exactly the thing a type system is in place to prevent.  If precision is important you want to be *more* specific with your types here.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would define a common representation as `Double` and an initializer which takes any `Numeric` type:

```
protocol Numeric {
    init(_ value : Numeric)
    var doubleValue: Double { get }

    // define some operators
    ...
}

// make Int, Float and Double conform to it
extension Int: Numeric {
    var doubleValue: Double { return Double(self) }
    init(_ value: Numeric) { self.init(value.doubleValue) }
}

extension Float: Numeric {
    var doubleValue: Double { return Double(self) }
    init(_ value: Numeric) { self.init(value.doubleValue) }
}

extension Double: Numeric {
    var doubleValue: Double { return self }
    init(_ value: Numeric) { self.init(value.doubleValue) }
}

// easy "casting" / converting from any Numeric type
let num: Numeric = 5.9
Int(num)
Float(num)
Double(num)
```

If you are using Swift 2 you can also make a protocol extension and add another initializer requirement in order to leave out the `init` declaration in the `Int`, `Float` and `Double` extension:

```
protocol Numeric {
    // Int, Float and Double already have this init
    init(_ double : Double)

    init(_ value : Numeric)
    var doubleValue: Double { get }

    // define some operators
    ...
}

extension Numeric {
    // provides a default initializer for all Numeric types
    // so they don't have to implement it themselves
    init(_ value: Numeric) {
        self.init(value.doubleValue)
    }
}
extension Int: Numeric {
    var doubleValue: Double { return Double(self) }
}

extension Float: Numeric {
    var doubleValue: Double { return Double(self) }
}

extension Double: Numeric {
    var doubleValue: Double { return self }
}
```